# How to print a single variable from PHP session array assigned from MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

PHP session array created from database and want to print to screen only one variable. I'm using this [guide](https://code-boxx.com/php-user-registration-form-email-verification/).

The array is created by :

```
$user = $libUsr->check($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
if ($user===false) { echo "ERR"; }
else {
$_SESSION['user'] = [
"name" => $user['user_name'],
"email" => $user['user_email'],
"status" => $user['user_status'],
"data" => $user['user_data']
];
echo "OK";
}
break;
```

The header of the signedin page after login is below, with start_session() called in 2a-config.php

```
require __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "lib" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "2a- 
config.php";
if (!is_array($_SESSION['user'])) {
header("Location: index.php");
die();
}
```

I've tried all combinations such as these (with the php tags of course):

```
echo $user["name"];
echo $user[1]["name"];
print_r(array_column($user, ‘name’));
```

Was even getting desperate as I've spent a lot of time on this and no other answers I found was working so was even trying

```
echo $_SESSION["name"];
echo $_SESSION[1]["name"];
```

As well as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635500/php-display-single-value-from-session-array) previously asked [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510828/pulling-two-single-variables-from-a-session-array) but still can't get it to work and no errors are coming up in my error log.

This is the array when I var dump.

```
ARRAY(1) { ["USER"]=> ARRAY(4) { ["NAME"]=> STRING(4) "TEST" ["EMAIL"]=> 
STRING(13) "TEST@TEST.COM" ["STATUS"]=> STRING(1) "A" ["DATA"]=> 
STRING(32) "9529C449206201FDBCE28CFA42FD48C8" } }
```

All I want is to just print the array variable "NAME" which is TEST to the screen. I'm hoping then I can workout how to pull out the user email in order to update my database. As you can see I'm a first time poster on Stack Overflow so apologies if my question is lacking. Thank you.

Comment: Whats `print_r($_SESSION)` show?

Comment: The key of your array is `user` so you can get your data with `$_SESSION['user']['name']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get single value from PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383914/how-to-get-single-value-from-php-array)

Comment: Yes @fdehanne, that is it. Thanks very much! The other question I was looking at had that but I'm so new to php I couldn't assign it to my own. Really appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
echo $_SESSION["user"]["name"];
```

Comment: yes that's it, thanks very much - I see now the same logic is on the others but I'm a rookie so couldn't apply it to my own. I'll remove this as it's a duplicate. Thank you for the answer though!